# Using jQuery within Tinymce - Specifically add a button to enable a div to be draggable

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce, draggable

I'm new to both jQuery and tinymce - been messing with it for a week or so.

I have initiated the jQuery version of tinymce - and correct me if I am wrong - I assumed that this will allow me to use jQuery within the editor instance itself - correct?

I use the tinymce instance to cover an entire page via a div tag named content.

I added a button to the tinymce instance that allows me to add a resizable div to the editor thus:

```
   setup :    function(ed) {
            ed.addButton('mybutton', {
                title : 'My button',
                image : 'img/example.gif',
                onclick : function() {
                    var aHtml = 
                        '<div class="isResizable">hello'+  
                        '</div>';
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus();
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, aHtml);

                }

            });
```

For resizable I used CSS:

```
       .isResizable {
        background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow: hidden;
        resize: both;
        width: 160px;
        height: 120px;
    }
```

I am now trying to figure out a way to make the newly inserted div element draggable. Does anyone know how to do this possibly by adding a new button to tinymce instance that will disable its editable state and enable a draggable state?

Can I add jquery functionality to a new button created as above in the tinymce initialisation?

Any other solutions would be gratefully appreciated as my head is now sore with banging it off the wall.

I changed the div that I create with the button to this:

```
<div id ="cheese" class="isResizable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">hello</div>
```

and included javascript functions for drag and drop on the page.

Draggable true appears in the new div but the ondragstart part is not inserted - so that's no use.

Figured it out, no jQuery required I simply forgot to make the div position absolute in the css..duhhhh!!